Missing Value in a dataset
i'm curently cleaning a dataset and theres a column called " Institution", it is needed for encoding and training the classification model later so it needs to be cleaned.
In that column, there are some input data recorded as "Unknown" or "Unavailable". Is this a kind of missing data that we need to clean (fill mode, mean ,etc) or i just need to leave it as it is and at the encoding stage, it will be encoded like a seperate class?
Thank you for answering !

You didn't tell us what you're using this data for. Presumably fed into some sort of model. But what kind? Show us the code you're running. Also, what fraction of institutions have an uncertain value? // Some models will seldom care about missing a few percent of such values. For example in the decison trees of XGBoost, we might never split on "unavailable". Validate this experimentally. Assign a distinct random value when the value is missing, and observe no meaningful change in $F_1$ performance.
